# CORS issue in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, content-security-policy

In one of my projects the csp is defined as

```
var csp = "default-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; sandbox allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts; base-uri 'self';";

if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Security-Policy"))
{
    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", csp);
}
```

The issue is that my internal JS is not working. I have included knockout JS and I get an error there.

*Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-SyLtUpmx0OjAxbTKXy2jd0BL8QnTwNgkVdWgf9/eQio='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*

*Uncaught EvalError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: if: sessionType() === ''
Message: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'".*

Getting this error in this line

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var returnUrl = '@Model.ReturnUrl';
    $(function () {
        $(":input").inputmask();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` is an inline script therefore you have got error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-SyLtUpmx0OjAxbTKXy2jd0BL8QnTwNgkVdWgf9/eQio='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution

You have 3 opts to allow inline script:

- to add `'insafe-inline'` token into `default-src` directive (it's severely reduces CSP protection)
- to add `'sha256-SyLtUpmx0OjAxbTKXy2jd0BL8QnTwNgkVdWgf9/eQio='` token into `default-src` directive (although it better to add `script-src 'self' 'sha256-SyLtUpmx0OjAxbTKXy2jd0BL8QnTwNgkVdWgf9/eQio='`). Negative moment: you have to regenerate a `'hash-value'` when you change the script's content.
- to add `'nonce-value'` into `default-src` or `script-src`. Nonce values should be generated fresh on each page loads, therefore it's better to use [NWebsec Tag Helpers](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/nwebsec/NWebsec.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.html)


  The error:

> Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'".

means you have use `eval()`, `new Function()` or `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()` function calls.
In case of `eval()`/`new Function()` you have no choice other than add `'unsafe-eval'` token into `default-src` (or `script-src` if you add it).
In case of `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()` - these counted as unsafe eval expressions only if get a function as string parameter. You can use anonymous (or named) function to avoid `'unsafe-eval'` usage.